# How to only query HealthKit for Total "In Bed" time for a given day?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

There isn't a whole of sample code on the internet for querying for sleep data.  The below code will return all sleep samples from a given day which if you look at the Apple Health App include "Asleep" samples from the Apple Watch which are sleep intervals, but there is also an "In Bed" sample from the iPhone which contains the total range from getting in bed to getting out of bed.  How can I query HealthKit for only this In Bed sample?

```
func sleepTime() {
        let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
        // startDate and endDate are NSDate objects
        // first, we define the object type we want
        if let sleepType = HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis) {
            // You may want to use a predicate to filter the data... startDate and endDate are NSDate objects corresponding to the time range that you want to retrieve
            //let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(startDate,endDate: endDate ,options: .None)
            // Get the recent data first
            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)
            // the block completion to execute
            let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sleepType, predicate: nil, limit: 100000, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, tmpResult, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    // Handle the error in your app gracefully
                    return
                }
                if let result = tmpResult {
                   for item in result {
                        if let sample = item as? HKCategorySample {
                               let startDate = sample.startDate
                               let endDate = sample.endDate
                               print()
                             let sleepTimeForOneDay = sample.endDate.timeIntervalSince(sample.startDate)
                        }
                    }
                }
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

HKCategorySample contains the *value* of type *Int* which is the enumeration value for the sample.
It has three values:

> 0 -> inBed
>
> 1 -> asleep
>
> 2 -> awake

So, the proposed change if you only want inBed data is:

```
if let result = tmpResult {
                for item in result {
                    if let sample = item as? HKCategorySample {
                        if sample.value == 0 {
                            let startDate = sample.startDate
                            let endDate = sample.endDate
                            print()
                            let sleepTimeForOneDay = sample.endDate.timeIntervalSince(sample.startDate)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Better way is to go with *switch* case.

```
if let result = tmpResult {
                for item in result {
                    if let sample = item as? HKCategorySample {
                        switch sample.value {
                        case 0:
                            // inBed, write logic here
                            print("inBed")
                        case 1:
                            // asleep, write logic here
                            print("asleep")
                        default:
                            // awake, write logic here
                            print("awake")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```